# WifiNetworkSpecifier does not trigger compile-time error

Tags: android

Using WifiNetworkSpecifier cause the following error if the app is running on a device with a version lower than Android 10

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Didn't find class "android.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSpecifier$Builder"
```

and I'm ok with that.

I just don't understand why that's not triggering a compile time error like other new features do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder` used to create WifiNetworkSpecifier objects.
**Added in API level 29**

It is very much possible you are missing the platform entirely.
Check if you have 29 platform downloaded , if not have it downloaded from SDK.

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't consider it. It looks like I was just missing an update, is it possible that the error check was added only in the 5th revision?

Comment: Well that could be it , but for me also sometimes it just doesn't work , so we just check if the platform was installed or not.